# jQuery Scale DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I would like to use this [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BzjjR/1/) or something similar to expand the container div from the center. So the  container div can expand to a specific size not a percentage. and the middle div shows. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/BzjjR/3/)

Note the use of `absolute` positioning and the `z-index` for the bottom overlay.

You don't need to hide the middle with jQuery, it will be hidden by default.

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply. like that but it needs to expand width ways as well at the same time. ;)

Comment: [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BzjjR/11/) it needs to expand horizontal at the same time. also needs to take in account all margins so needs to always be centered.

Comment: expand horizontally to what dimensions?  .animate will take a list of properties to transform- how's this: http://jsfiddle.net/BzjjR/11/

Comment: initial dimensions: width: 272px;  height: 425px;
transform to: width: 300px; height: 621px;

Comment: Oops, didn't save before posting the link: http://jsfiddle.net/BzjjR/12/  ... You should be able to change the height and width of the container in the CSS or in the transformation pretty easily.